# Voltage between shower faucet and drain

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, grounding

Is it normal to have voltage between shower faucet and drain?

I measured **2 volts** between shower faucet and drain when water heater is off, and **11-12 volts** when it is on?

Comment: I have to ask...what prompted you to make this measurement?

Comment: Nigth before, I felt stinging electricity when I touch shower faucet with my finger. Even though, the skin of part finger is slightly damaged, I decided to make a measurement.

Comment: What kind of water heater is this, and where (bathroom vs. other side of the house, etc.) is it installed?

Comment: It is electric water heater and it is in other part of the house, other room. @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact

Comment: How did you measure? Just a voltmeter would read floating voltage, which is meaningless. 2 or 12 volts would also not leave any visible damage to your skin

Comment: I use regular multimeter. I set multimeter to ~200 V, put red lead on shower faucet and black lead on top of drain. I had damage on my skin previously. It isn't from stinging electricity, I forgot mention.

Comment: Ah, so you had an open wound of some sort and felt the tingle of electricity in the previously open wound. That may be somewhat more sensitive an area that "normal" undamaged skin.

Comment: can you take your multi meter and switch it to current, then measure as before? If it's a milliamp or so, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I called electrician. The problem is solved! Neutral wire had fault in junction box on poles. Not only I had problem my neighbour had problem to (when he turn oven the fuse pops up). This was in my rented flat so I didn't know what and how is ground made. Because the flat has no separate ground wire, the ground was connected to neutral and beacuse wire had fault in junction box on poles we had problem.

Comment: Now, voltage  between shower faucet and drain is under 1 (V) even water heater is on. Before, the worst case was when I measured 44(V).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not normal and dangerous. I suggest that you hire an electrician or least favorable option (ground is like crazy science to regular person and there are a lot of gotcha ya), do your own research. It looks like there is insufficient grounding and your heater or some other appliance has a ground fault. All of the electrical circuits and appliances must be grounded and all metallic piping must be bonded.

Comment: Wouldn't you consider asking here at least part of "do your own research"?

Answer (score -1):

Damaged skin reduces your body’s natural resistance so you felt the shock.

This low voltage can be generated in many ways and at that low of a voltage is not dangerous.

the National electric code article 411 low voltage lighting: think swimming pools hot tubs where this lighting is normally used allows 15 volts ac where wet contact is likely.

I regularly bond the hot water pipe to the cold water pipe if metallic many jurisdictions require this as the NEC if likely to become energized it shall be bonded to the grounding electrode system.

Another possibility is an imbalanced electrical system. A heavy imbalance can cause a voltage to be present on the neutral & grounding system that a well balanced system will not have.

No one likes getting shocked so taking steps to eliminate the cause (other than broken skin) like making sure the water piping is grounded both hot and cold. Getting the home balanced L1 to L2 I have seen 50 amp imbalances cause much higher neutral voltages and once the system was balanced no voltage on the grounded or grounding conductors (moving breakers to even out loading for each leg.)

The good thing is this is not considered hazardous but I would be at least adding additional grounding to eliminate it.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote other than that those that don’t know code values.